# How to convert cond statements that produces a boolean value into an expression involving only not, and and or

Tags: boolean, scheme, racket, boolean-expression, boolean-algebra

I am learning about racket/scheme and came across an online resource that said, if a function written using a cond gives true or false, it can be rewritten using only **not**, **and**, and **or**. I have worked out some simple examples where I was able to to convert cond statements into a statement only involving not and and or. My question is if there is a way that the logic can be "seen" right away when converting between these two types of statements. I understand that it is not always practical to convert every cond statement into a combination of not's and's and or's but I am interested in learning about the logic behind the process of converting.
Thanks in advance.

(If something about the question does not make sense, leave a comment and I will try clarifying what I want to understand)

Comment: You should perhaps give an example of a `cond` you don't see how to convert?

Comment: I do not have an example of a cond I do not see how to convert. I am just wondering if there is some logical method/algorithm to convert any cond statement that results in a Boolean value into a combination of not and and or.

Comment: It's too complex to explain here, but look up Karnaugh maps and Boolean algebra.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @am121 it is wrong. Km are used to compress boolean expressions.

Answer (score 3):

All conditional expressions (and not only those evaluating to true/false) can be rewritten using only boolean combinators. This is because of how logical operators are evaluated in Scheme/Racket. For instance, logically `(and a b)` would be true if both `a` and `b` are true, and otherwise false. But in Racket, the result of `(and a b)` is `b` if both `a` and `b` are truthy, and otherwise false. That is, evaluation proceeds to the right until either the last argument or a falsy value is encountered. At that point, evaluation stops and that value (which could be a boolean but needn't be) is returned. It's because `and` and `or` don't simply produce boolean output that they can be used to stand in for conditional expressions.

E.g.

```
(if #t 'hello 'bye) ;=> hello
(or (and #t 'hello) 'bye) ;=> hello
(if #f 'hello 'bye) ;=> bye
(or (and #f 'hello) 'bye) ;=> bye
(cond [#f 'hello]
      [#f 'bye]
      [#t 'aloha]) ;=> aloha
(or (and #f 'hello)
    (and #f 'bye)
    (and #t 'aloha)) ;=> aloha
```

But you wouldn't usually want to use them that way since they're hard to read. As a general guideline, use `if` and `cond` in most cases, rather than elementary boolean operators. If you only care about taking action on a positive or negative result of the conditional, then you could use `when` or `unless`. If you do care about handling both positive and negative results, but one of them is a boolean result such as this example:

```
(if (positive? n)
  #t
  (even? n))
```

... then this would be a case where a boolean operator would be preferable, like so:

```
(or (positive? n) (even? n))
```

If both arms of the `if` conditional are boolean values, like this:

```
(if (> n 3)
  #t
  #f)
```

... then just replace the entire conditional expression with the condition itself:

```
(> n 3)
```

Otherwise, stick to `if` and `cond`.

Comment: You can't write, e.g., `(if some-condition #f #t)` as `(or (and some-condition #f) #t)`. Of course, a conditional is the wrong way to express negation, but OP seems to be asking about `cond` expressions that evaluate to a boolean value.

Comment: That's a good point, `#f` values in the consequent position would warrant special handling. For this particular example, following the guideline in the answer it would be written `(not some-condition)` instead, but you're right that this doesn't address the general case of falsy consequent expressions.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate all the examples.

Comment: re false consequent, indeed `(or (and #t #f) 'bye) ;=> bye` but 
`(or (and #t #f) (and (not #t) 'bye)) ;=> #f`, correctly. probably also need to introduce a temp var via `let`, in general.

Answer (score 2):

Once you convert a `cond` to nested `if`s, you can always turn it into `and` `or` and `not` like this:

```
(if A B C) --> (or (and A B) (and (not A) C))
```

However, if you do this blindly, you will get a much more complicated expression than what you could get, so I would add a couple more transformations you can use:

```
(if A B #f) --> (and A B)
(if A B #t) --> (or (not A) B)
(if A #f C) --> (and (not A) C)
(if A #t C) --> (or A C)
```

(note: that `or` above might return a different truthy-value other than `#t`, making it technically different but equivalent-when-used-as-a-boolean)

Another thing I should note is that sometimes you can transform a multi-branch `cond` into `and` `or` `not` without transforming into `if`s first. For example a 3-branch `cond`:

```
(cond [A B]
      [C D]
      [else E])
-->
(or (and A B)
    (and (not A) C D)
    (and (not A) (not C) E))
```

Or a 4-branch `cond`:

```
(cond [A B]
      [C D]
      [E F]
      [else G])
-->
(or (and A B)
    (and (not A) C D)
    (and (not A) (not C) E F)
    (and (not A) (not C) (not E) G))
```

Each `and` corresponds to a cond-branch, and each cond-branch's `and` has `not`s in it for every previous condition, in addition to its own condition.

A more generic rule you can apply:

```
for i from 1 through n,
(cond [Q_i A_i]
      ...
      [else E])
-->
on each i, for j from 1 through i-1,
(or (and (not Q_j) ... Q_i A_i)
    ...
    (and (not Q_i) ... E)
```

Comment: `(lambda (x) (not (not x)))` will turn a truthy value into a Boolean one.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to desugar cond language into a sequence of if-then-else sequences, which is trivial.

After that, you can rewrite if conditionals into  boolean operators.  You can look into a manual of propositional logic to learn this.  Or look [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Combining-Conditions.html).

Btw.  It is forbidden to paste your homework on stack overflow.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yup I'll make sure not to ask homework questions on stack overflow.

Comment: @user14346904  You can ask questions, but you need to show what did you try, not only the question itself.   Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.